# In wordpress, how to show next and previous post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am able to display next and previous post in worspress but unable to show second-previous or third-previous || second-next or third-next like

1 - **I want to show this too** 
2 - this is showing 
3 - **My Current post** 
4 - This is showing 
5 - **I want to show this too**

any help would be appreciated.
In the and I am showing you my code so you can judge.

CODE:

```
<?php $next = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)); if
($next != get_permalink()) { ?><a href="<?php echo $next; ?>">
    <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="article">
            <div class="contain-image">
            <?php $nextPost = get_next_post(true); $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID); echo $nextthumbnail; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="double-content">
                    <div class="information">
                        <span class="category"><?php echo get_cat_name(1);?></span>
                        <span class="time"><?php the_time('M j, Y') ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <?php next_post_link('%link', "%title", TRUE); ?>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        <?php 
                        $Nextpost = get_next_post($id);
                        echo apply_filters(‘the_content’, $Nextpost->post_content);
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</a>
<?php } ?>
<?php $prev = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(true,'',true)); if
($prev != get_permalink()) { ?><a href="<?php echo $prev; ?>">
    <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="article">
            <div class="contain-image">
            <?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(true); $prevThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID); echo $prevThumbnail; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="double-content">
                    <div class="information">
                        <span class="category"><?php echo get_cat_name(1);?></span>
                        <span class="time"><?php the_time('M j, Y') ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <?php previous_post_link('%link', "%title", TRUE); ?>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                    <?php 
                        $Prevpost = get_previous_post($id);
                        echo apply_filters(‘the_content’, $Prevpost->post_content);
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides several navigational template tags to make it easy for visitors to surf your pages. There are basically two different types of template tags used for chronological post navigation:

```
posts_nav_link() – for navigating various archive (non-single) pages
previous_post_link() & next_post_link() – for navigating single-post pages


<?php $posts = query_posts($query_string); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php previous_post_link(); ?> | <?php next_post_link(); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    global $post;
    $post_curr = $post;

    //get last post
    $post_last1 = get_previous_post();
    setup_postdata($post_last1);
    //get second last post
    $post_last2 = get_previous_post();


    setup_postdata($post_curr);
    //get next post now
    $post_next1 = get_next_post();
    setup_postdata($post_next1);
    //get second next post
    $post_next2 = get_next_post();

    //reset current post data
    setup_postdata($post_curr);
```

Comment: Hi I did as you said but nothing happend